# Is it possible to set up for two different urls one cache page in varnish?

Tags: varnish

I have two sites with different domains and url building (one of them using subdomain in url and other convert subdomain to path) and I want to make varnish one varnish cache for this two urls? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the default VCL defines the hash of content as:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  hash_data(req.url);

  if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
  } else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
  }

  return (lookup);
}
```

Which includes the `Host` header. Redefining the `vcl_hash` function to something like the following will make it share objects across diffrent hosts.

```
sub vcl_hash {
  hash_data(req.url);
  return (lookup);
}
```